# How to convert from string to enum value in c++?

Tags: c++, enums

I have an enum like this

```
enum week{Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri, Sat, Sun};
```

I am trying to get the index value of the enum by passing a string value.

For example, `GetenumIndex("Mon")` will return `0`.

The prototype of the function is like:

```
week GetenumIndex(string )
```

What is the idiomatic way in C++ to implement such a conversion function?

Comment: That should be quite easy using a number of `if() else if()` statements. Did you already try that?

Comment: There's something very important that's missing from your question. That would be an actual, specific, question.

Comment: You could use a [map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) that maps a string to an enumeration value.

Comment: thnx man  now i edited .Now can you help me @SamVarshavchik

Comment: No. There's still no actual programming question anywhere to be found. "Can anyone help me" is not a specific programming question.

Comment: @user8364661 I'd recommend you to accept or adopt my edit, to fix that problem with your question.

Comment: @tobi303 I agree. But aren't duplicates more useful if fomulated in a canonical way? (TBH, instead of that _mentoring_ shit discussed at Meta SO, I believe that editing questions is way more constructive).

Comment: @user0042 if formulated in a canonical way, then yes, but this question isnt so its probably easiest to simply close it

Comment: @user0042 I dont know what is the Meta opinion an that, but imho it makes more sense to close a low quality question instead of improving it just do flag it as duplicate

Comment: @tobi303 I referred to my edit, that shaped it into a canonical way.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here you go:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <exception>

enum week{Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri, Sat, Sun};

week GetenumIndex( const std::string s ) {    
    static std::map<std::string,week> string2week {
       { "Mon", Mon }, 
       { "Tue", Tue },
       { "Wed", Wed }, 
       { "Thur", Thur },
       { "Fri", Fri },
       { "Sat", Sat }, 
       { "Sun", Sun }   
    };
    auto x = string2week.find(s);
    if(x != std::end(string2week)) {
        return x->second;
    }
    throw std::invalid_argument("s");
}

int main() {
    week w = GetenumIndex("Thur");
    std::cout << w << std::endl;
}
```

See it live [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f58ee448924c7ab).

Comment: @user8364661 Well, closing that question as duplicate was correct.